# scala: How to remove a String from mulitple DataFrame Columns whose values are Array[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a DataFrame where multiple columns contain values of type Array[String] (up to X Columns).

```
| col1          | col2          | col3          |
| ----------------------------------------------|
| Array[String] | Array[String] | Array[String] |
| ...                                           |
```

I have another list of strings (not within the DataFrame) which are words that I absolutely hate and don't want in my DataFrame.

`val bad_words = Array("doctor","saint")`

I want to search through every Column with Array[String] as its type, and remove the individual strings within the array whose contents match one of the words in the bad_words list, i.e.

Before:

```
| col1: Array[String]                      | col2: Array[String]                        |
| -----------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------|
| ["donut","Frisbee","phone","doctor"]     | ["I don't like the doctor","Bob Swagga"]   |
| ["Dorothy M. is a saint","I'm a banana"] | ["eenie","meenie","miney","Moe"]           |
```

After:

```
| col1: Array[String]                      | col2: Array[String]                        |
| -----------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------|
| ["donut","Frisbee","phone"]              | ["Bob Swagga"]                             |
| ["I'm a banana"]                         | ["eenie","meenie","miney","Moe"]           |
```

As illustrated, I also want to check whether the bad_words are a substring of any strings in the Array.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to define a UDF.

```
def removeBadWords(input: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {

   val badWords: Seq[String] = ???

   input.filter{ // Logic to filter strings containing bad words}
}

val badWordsUdf = udf(removeBadWords(_: Seq[String]))

def.select(badWordsUdf($"col1"), badWordsUdf($"col2"))
```